# How to check if a module is available for import?

Tags: python, module, styles

I am using a module in a script but one action inside the host application doesn't load this module so the script fails. It's fine if it fails because it doesn't need to run, but I don't want to see the error message box.

Is there a way to check if the module is available, like:

```
isavailable ( mymodule )

# safe to use the module
```

But I also want the function to early return, break the execution if it's not available.

Comment: Is this one of your own modules, or part of a package that was installed as a setuptools distribution?

Comment: It's a built in module but not mine or python's. It's the app's own module that's loaded at startup.

Comment: Ok, then @kroolik's answer is the way to go. (In case of a setuptools package it would have been better to check for `pkg_resources.get_distribution('foobar')`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
try:
    import my_module
except ImportError:
    available = False
else:
    available = True
```

Comment: Wouldn't this, in fact, import the module? I suppose you could define a function that does this e.g. `def import_avail(module): try: __import__(module) except ImportError: return False else: return True` but otherwise you'll have one heck of a side effect!

Comment: @adsmith, you can move the `try: import except: else:` clause into `eval` and check for errors/sentinel variables. And yes, by importing you are exposing yourself to side-effects of the module's init, but then, I would really reevaluate if I would use a module that fires a bomb on import.

Comment: Thanks, btw do you know if I can just halt the execution using return? I am not inside a function, but I want the rest of the commands that comes after not to be executed. Not sure how I could modify your code to do that. I guess I can just encapsulate the rest of the code in an if statement but it's long.

Comment: @JoanVenge, I would go with ``raise ImportError('Module `my_module` is not available.')`` and handle the `ImportError` in the importing module, but that depends on your use case. Sometimes you might want to mock `my_module` with `my_module_compat` when the prior is not available, `try: import my_module except ImportError: import my_module_compat as my_module`. `my_module_compat` would either implement a noop variant of `my_module`, or whole different implementation.

Comment: @kroolik: Why `raise ImportError(…)`? You're just handling `ImportError` by raising an almost-identical error with a different message…

Comment: @abarnert, So that somebody importing the module directly could get a more verbose error message giving them clue about the situation. Possibly, since that module is optional, the user should import from a module wrapping that functionality which in turn would provide suitable replacements. It's not like `No module named 'my_module'` isn't verbose enough, but in this particular case that little more verbosity wouldn't hurt.

Comment: @kroolik: I don't think it _is_ optional. The OP says that it's fine if it fails, the program doesn't need to run if it's missing, and she wants to "break the execution". I think she just wants to hide the exception traceback. Turning it into a different exception doesn't help that.

Comment: @abarnert, it's just a matter of taste how would you like to stop the execution, and what actually the rest of the statements is. If the code includes `main`-of-sort function, you can replace it to just print a message. If the module was to provide an object that would serve something - change it to noop. Or you could just use `sys.exit(1)`. Every solution has it's caveats and it's a matter of taste (and the actual design of the app) to choose the most suitable one.

Comment: @kroolik: My point is that no matter _which_ solution you choose, replacing the `ImportError` with a slightly different `ImportError` is not going to help with that solution, it just adds three extra lines of code for no reason. (Remember, the main thing she's asking for is to not see the error, so either changing the text of the error is invisible, or you didn't actually solve her problem.) BTW, if it's not clear, it's not your answer (which is good) that I'm commenting on here, but your comment saying "I would go with…". I don't see what you expect that to improve.

Comment: @abarnert, most likely because if I had been to implement such behaviour in my app, I would hide it behind a module that would provide a sane replacement, or at least a verbose message that would give people working on the app, or using it, any clue on what has happened rather than killing the whole app with `sys.exit(1)`. There could also be a case that somebody was importing parts of the app in his app, but the app get killed without sane way to recover (except for `except SystemExit`). I'm aware this might not be the case here, but it might influence the design of OP's app.

Comment: @kroolik: I agree with you that "hide the error complete and just silently exit" is probably not a great design… but it's the design the OP explicitly asked for help implementing.

Comment: Doesn't this break the pep8 standards? "E402 module level import not at top of file"

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following:

```
import importlib

def import_if_available(name, package=None):
    try:
        return importlib.import_module(name, package)
    except ImportError:
        return None

print import_if_available('os.path')
```

From [importlib](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/importlib.html#) documentation.

*The purpose of the importlib package is two-fold. One is to provide an implementation of the import statement (and thus, by extension, the **import**() function) in Python source code. This provides an implementation of import which is portable to any Python interpreter. This also provides a reference implementation which is easier to comprehend than one implemented in a programming language other than Python.
Two, the components to implement import are exposed in this package, making it easier for users to create their own custom objects (known generically as an importer) to participate in the import process. Details on custom importers can be found in PEP 302.*

Comment: No reason to do this rather than just a regular import.

Comment: Your answer also hardcodes the module name, and the question doesn't indicate that the module name needs to be dynamic.

Comment: Answer edited, my previous version of the answer was addressing to this version.

Comment: `import_if_available("namespace.package")` - oops, doesn't work. That's why you shouldn't use [`__import__`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#__import__) unless you really know what you're doing.

Comment: @LukasGraf what about now? ;)

Comment: The `os` in `os.path` is not a namespace package, it's just a regular module. See [`zope.interface`](https://github.com/zopefoundation/zope.interface), [`zope.component`](https://github.com/zopefoundation/zope.component), etc. for an example of a namespace package (`zope`). Your code now can handle them though, because of the use of `importlib.import_module` instead of `__import__`, so +0.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to check if a module is available is to import it. And this is almost always what you want, as well. If the module isn't available, this will fail. If the module is available… well, the reason you're checking is because you need to verify that you will be able to import it, so you're not wasting any time importing it now.

More generally, in Python, it's [easier to ask forgiveness than permission](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp). If you want to know whether you *can* do something, just try to do it.

So, this is almost an answer on its own:

```
import mymodule
```

The code will "early return, break the execution if it's not available." The only problem is that you don't want to see the error message.

There are two ways around this.

---

First, you could wrap the code up like this:

```
try:
    import mymodule
except ImportError:
    pass
else:
    # everything else you were going to do.
```

Whether "the code" is the whole function body, or the line of code that calls the function, or a chunk of top-level code in your script or module, or whatever, it makes no difference.

---

If you want to avoid the extra block indent, you can "return early" in various different ways. (Although really, it's almost always trivial to just extract all the indented code out into a new function, which means you end up with just a one-line function call being in the `else` block.)

How you do that depends on what level you're trying to return from, and that isn't clear from your question. If you want to return early from a function, just `return` (possibly with an appropriate value). If you want to return early from the whole program, just `sys.exit(0)`. So:

```
try:
    import mymodule
except ImportError:
    sys.exit(0)
# the rest of your code
```

You could also `exit` with a positive value, which is a way to tell the shell or whoever else called your program that it "failed", without printing out an error traceback.

Answer (score 1):

Although it's a little unusual to want a called function to halt execution, you *can* do it, as shown below. You'll have to pass the module's *name* as a string to the function, since presumably the variable `mymodule` won't exist yet when it's called. If it's successful it will return the imported module so the result can be assigned to variable name for subsequent use.

```
import sys

def isavailable(modulename):
    try:
        module = __import__(modulename)
    except ImportError:
        sys.exit(1)  # stop execution
    else:
        return module
```

Sample usage:

```
mymodule = isavailable('mymodule')  # program will terminate if not found
mymodule.method()
```

Comment: Same as with @Raydel's answer: `isavailable("namespace.package")` will fail.

Comment: @LukasGraf see my new version.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this comes late, but I believe that an easy way to check for this would be using the `sys.modules` dict:

```
import sys

if 'my_module' in sys.modules: 
    print ('Module available')
else:
    print ('Module not available')
```

If you want to put this in a function:

```
import sys

def isavailable(m):
    if m in sys.modules: 
        return True
    else:
        return False

isavailable('mymodule')
```

Answer (score 0):

sys.modules check appears to be more elegant? Unfortunately while working in notebook, does not seem to work when used in py file when run as
python mycode.py.
Have no idea why - I guess "replace user and press anykey?"

```
import sys

# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20957811/how-to-check-if-a-module-is-available-for-import
if 'geopandas' in sys.modules:
    print ('geopandas is available')
else:
    print ('geopandas is not available') # for whatever reason prints this when in fact is available

# redundant, just for the record

try:
    import geopandas as gpd
except ImportError:
    print('Geopandas is not available. Please "conda install geopandas",\n \
    or switch environment where geopandas is installed "conda activate geopandas_env_name"')
    sys.exit(0)
# the rest of your code

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```